# Could not Load File or Assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I am running an MVC Web Application. One of the features of the app is to generate a PDF report. The PDF Report also shows a Map. However on generating the PDF, it gives an error message:-

```
"Could not Load File or Assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version = 11.0.0.0, Culture = neutral,publicKeyToken = 89845dcd8080cc91" or one of its dependencies. The System cannot find the file specified.
```

We do have references to Microsoft Report Viewer (Version 11) to the following three assemblies:-

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
```

I don't find Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization. Where do I get it from ?

Answer (score 0):

From Microsof Sql Server Management Studio for Example.
Why do you use the old 11 Version?
You can use with the 14. version which come with SSMS Version 17.4.
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with v14.  Had to pull in the DLL from the package folder manually:
packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.140.1000.523\lib